# How to bind this with Higher order functions

Tags: javascript, class, this, bind, higher-order-functions

I have this higher-order function in some file

**withTry.js**

```js
function withTry(func){
    return function(...args) {
        try{
            
            func(...args);
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it in another file like this;

**foo.js**

```js
const withTry = require('path');

function someClass(){
 this.m = null;
 this.s=0;
}

/*I am using the withTry in class prototypes*/
someClass.prototype.func = withTry(function(data){
 /* 
  The problem is here
  The value of "this" is global which makes sense because it refers to the global of the withTry HOF
*/

 console.log(this.s) /*undefined*/
 
});
```

My question is how to bind the "this" of the "someClass"

Comment: I'm assuming you are calling `func` somehow, could you add to the question exactly how you're calling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to *bind* it, you want to pass the dynamic `this` value through:

```
function withTry(func) {
    return function(...args) {
        try {
            func.call(this, ...args);
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^
        } catch(error){
            console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`)
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative to [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), you can also use [`func.apply(this, args)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Next thing you'll want to add is a `return` statement for passing the return value back out :-)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is basically the same as Bergi's:

```js
function withTry(func){
    return function(...args) {
        try{
            
            // func(...args);
            func.apply(this, args)
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`)
        }
    }
}

function someClass(){
 this.m = null;
 this.s=2;
}

someClass.prototype.func = withTry(function(data){
 console.log(this.s); 
});

var x = new someClass();
x.func();
```

I realized that, because you're calling `x.func`, the function returned from `withTry` would have the right `this` already